# ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED error on emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, device-emulation

Pocket PC 2003 SE Emulator is connected and cradled.

Deployment successfully succeeded, but after Debug Starting:
The operation could not be completed. Device is not connected.

I have also tried:

Device Security Manager -> Windows CE Device
[image]

I have also tried to delete CoreCon\1.0 - no changes.

Comment: what does "delete CoreCon\1.0" mean?  Deleted from where?  Not the PC I surely hope.  If you deleted that, then a reinstall is in your future (or maybe, with luck, a copy from another PC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the debugger is starting, so I am going to go with the assumption that this is correct.

Another assumption: This is a Forms application (not a library or other).

- Open the code window for **Form1** and place a breakpoint on the constructor.
- Run the code (F5).
- When your breakpoint is reached, step through each line (F10).

When you get to the line in your code that is causing the problem, look at that line to see what it is doing. It sounds like you are trying to establish some kind of connection in your constructor.

**Update:**

Using the information found [>> HERE <<](http://us.generation-nt.com/cant-get-c-app-debugging-working-wince-6-0-help-81613482.html), try the following:

> Check that you don't have any firewall enabled on your PC and that there is enough free space on the device object store. If your OS image does not include the .NET compact framework you may need to add support for CAB installer inside the image to allow Visual
>   Studio to deploy it.
>
> Check also that the ConManClient2, CMAccept and other executables that are installed on the device are for the same version of the .NET CF and VS2005 service pack that you have on your PC. You should find them under:
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target
>   \wce400\ARMV4I
>
> Try to copy those files from your PC to the \Windows subdir of your device and run ConnManClient2 and CMAccept manually and check if it works.

Comment: This error is also with real device: Connect to device failed. - Device Connectivity Component.

Comment: Device Security Manager -> Windows CE Device Connection Failed

Connection failed. An existing connection has been closed by the remote host

Comment: It seems like I ran into that issue before. I've updated the answer with some more ideas to try. For me, though, it seems like I only got this fixed by getting upset, uninstalling all of the Compact Frameworks, uninstalling Visual Studio, then reinstalling Visual Studio and then the Frameworks. I never did find a good solution.

Comment: It's typically a result of a network block (firewall), not running CMAccept, or having mismatched device/PC corecon bits.

Comment: Solution: Perfom hard reset of Win CE device. This is device problem!

Comment: It may have been that the device had the network password stored, that password expired, and you had no way of changing it. @ctacke told me about resetting that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/71f1c236-488e-4cf4-b41a-55bc0c808396) back in 2009.